# Why do subsequent runs of scala function go orders of magnitude faster?

Tags: scala, timing

I'm having a very weird phenomenon occur. I'm hashing some mockup ssoids, and timing it since our application is timing critical. The first run of the function takes ~210 *milliseconds*, which is ridiculous and won't work. However, the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th runs take a few thousand *nanoseconds* each. I'm really confused, what's going on? Is there some caching I can do to make the first run just as fast?

See the code here:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val qq = "847bf1dc46ca22dc93259c5e857d6333"
    val oo = "847bf1dc46ca22dc9eriuerie9duy45"
    val xx = "909909ewufv9026854509erie9ifkf3"
    val ww = "65984jg3oiqh4g3q383423932824344"
    val qqq = getBytes(qq)
    val ooo = getBytes(oo)
    val xxx = getBytes(xx)
    val www = getBytes(ww)
    val t1 = System.nanoTime
    val r1 = XxHash64.hashByteArray(qqq, seed = 0)
    val duration = (System.nanoTime - t1)
    val t2 = System.nanoTime
    val r2 = XxHash64.hashByteArray(ooo, seed = 0)
    val duration2 = (System.nanoTime - t2)
    val t3 = System.nanoTime
    val r3 = XxHash64.hashByteArray(xxx, seed = 0)
    val duration3 = (System.nanoTime - t3)
    val t4 = System.nanoTime
    val r4 = XxHash64.hashByteArray(www, seed = 0)
    val duration4 = (System.nanoTime - t4)
    println(duration)
    println(duration2)
    println(duration3)
    println(duration4)
    println(r1)
    println(r2)
    println(r3)
    println(r4)
  }
```

(Also note I recognize this is a slipshod way of doing timings, but I've just started.)

Comment: If it's running on JVM, then it's JIT. Actually, if it's running on a JS engine, it's also JIT, but for js, not for java...

Comment: Ignore the first run. In fact, ignore the other three too. Make a loop, with 10,000 runs or so, throw out 1,000 best and worst, and take the average of what's left, that'll give you something remotely resembling a proxy to expected real life performance.  Also, use the same input data for every run. As you said yourself, this is _not_ a way to do benchmarking, so there really no point in wasting time on looking at these timings.

Comment: @ Andrey, ty I'll look up JIT. @ Dima I will do that, but I really care about the first run not taking ~200 ms. In the actual application, it will only get invoked once, so while I plan to do the average timing, I still need to know how to make the first run fast, so it's not really a waste of time.

Comment: @troyblerg "only get invoked once" PER JVM SESSION? If that's the case, I don't see any reason to care about performance of anything taking under a second to begin with. It takes longer to start and stop the JVM ...

Comment: Skip the loops also, use JMH for benchmarking. If you want to run some microsecond-long operation just once, then rolling the JVM out of the hangar is already totally overkill. You could try Scala Native though, if you really want to write it in Scala.

Comment: @ dima, we're a bit out of my wheelhouse, but this is going to run on a ecs in a docker container where it will get invoked when it is needed by an API. I don't know enough about aws to say if it's always running on ecs or if it's booted when a request is made, I suppose it's always running, but I don't want to make assumptions.

@ andrey, okay thank you, the rest of the bigger app is in scala so I think I'm stuck using it though. I'll look up scala native and JHM, thank you

Comment: You don't have to make assumptions if you don't want to ... You just need to realize, that launching the docker container, starting up the JVM in it, reading the request from network, and sending the response back will take at least several seconds. So, whether the actual calculation takes one nanosecond or half a second is totally inconsequential in that scenario

Comment: @troyblerg I had some success chasing milliseconds with GraalVM via https://github.com/scalameta/sbt-native-image. This was on AWS Lambdas but the concept should be similar as I assume underlying implementation is relying on spinning up containers.

Comment: Some recent [performance benchmarks](https://medium.com/virtuslab/revisiting-scala-native-performance-67029089f241) that might be of interest.